# Multi windowed Java application

Tags: java, netbeans

I am wondering what is the best practise for creating a multi windowed Java application? For example, say I was creating an instant messenger -

1. When the application starts it should show a window with fields for username & password, and two buttons, one for login and one for create account.
2. If the user clicks the create account button, the initial window should close and a new one should appear with a form for the user to create an account
3. If the user instead clicks login, the initial window should close and the main application window should appear.

I am wondering how this can be accomplished in Java and how should the code be organised? In C# I used the ModelViewViewModel design pattern, is there some similar recommended pattern when it comes to Java?

(And I am using Netbeans IDE if anyone has some Netbeans specific advice.)

Answer (score 2):

how about using [Netbeans Platform](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/)?